# Calculating historical volatility and returns from bond yield

Tags: volatility, fixed-income, bond, portfolio-optimization, yield

I am interested to calculate the historical volatility and returns from a time series of US 3m T-bill yield (see screenshot below), for portfolio optimization. I am not too sure how to bridge the idea of using US 3m T-bill yield to calculate the above, so any help will be great!

[image]

Comment: What is the frequency of returns used in your optimization? Weekly, monthly, quarterly?

Comment: @AlexC I am looking to do it daily.

Comment: To keep constant maturity, it would be ideal to find an index which represents constant maturity Treasuries exposure.

Comment: @LisaAnn Thank you for getting back to me. Do you think the Treasury 3m bills from the Fed can be used?

Comment: @fauxpas: if you have the yield time series, first it would be better to build the time series of a synthetic zero coupon bond. This trick allows for taking into account the link between yield volatility and price volatility in a more accurate way than using proxies like second order expansion through duration and convexity. Once you have the price time series, you can plug its first differences into your portfolio optimization routine.

Comment: @LisaAnn Could you point me to the direction as to how to build the time series of a synthetic zero coupon bond? Also, by doing so, you're effectively assuming the synthetic zero coupon bond now has constant maturity of 3m, am I right?

Comment: @fauxpas: yes, I'm assuming that because in your ideal optimized portfolio you would rebalance your T-Bill exposure by buying new 3M bills, so keeping the maturity as much constant as possible. To build the synthetic price just use the formula $p_{t}=\frac{100}{\left(1+y_{t}\right)^{T}}$, where $y_{t}$ is the yield time series and $T$ the 3M maturity expressed in years (e.g. $0.25$). Last, differentiate $\ln\left(p_{t}\right)$ to get returns for your portfolio model.